# Как работают telegram-боты на скриптовых и компилируемых языках?

Tags: php, java, python, telegram-bot, веб-сервер

## Режимы получения обновлений telegram бота

Я хочу создать telegram-бота. Есть два режима его работы:

- LongPolling
- WebHook

**LongPolling** - это когда приложение само ходит на сервера telegram с какой-то периодичностью и спрашивает, не появилось ли чего-нибудь новенького для меня?

**WebHook** - когда telegram сам уведомляет мое приложение о новых сообщениях.

### LongPolling на скриптовом языке

Если я пишу бота на python или php, где процесс не живет в системе, а запускается nginx'ом отрабатывает и сразу умирает, то каким образом будет работать long polling метод? Кто будет опрашивать сервера telegram на наличие обновлений, если постоянно живущего процесса в системе нет?

### WebHook на Java

Если я работаю через webhook, и пишу бота на java, где процесс живет постоянно, то мне нужно поднимать tomcat и создавать endpoint для зарегистрированного вебхука? Или если имплементировать метод `getBotPath()` абстрактного класса `TelegramWebhookBot`, то веб-сервер сам поднимется?

Иначе я не пойму: telegram отправляет http-запрос на указанный мною url, и должен же быть какой-то веб-сервер, способный этот http-запрос обработать.

Comment: В php уже давно вроде как демоны есть.

Comment: Скрипт на любом языке, хоть компилируемом хоть нет может работать как из под веб-сервера так и самостоятельно. Тут вопрос исключительно того, как вы его запустите.

Comment: А для java есть масса вариантов запуска, включая вообще встроенные http сервера, ну либо внешние. как вам больше нравится. (варианты искать в гугле по запросу "java http server")

Comment: тогда вопрос по телеграм-библиотеке для java от самого telegram: после реализации методов класса org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramWebhookBot нужно ли еще дополнительно поднимать Tomcat?